# PHP global keyword inside function is not working

Tags: php, variables, scope

Consider the following code

```
// Grab some values to be used later ('Y' or 'N')
$daycareactive = isActiveProgramType($companyid,'daycare');
$oscactive = isActiveProgramType($companyid,'osc');
$preschoolactive = isActiveProgramType($companyid,'preschool');
$ecsactive = isActiveProgramType($companyid,'ecs');
$grouphomeactive = isActiveProgramType($companyid,'grouphome');
$dayhomeactive = isActiveProgramType($companyid,'dayhome');
$otheractive = isActiveProgramType($companyid,'other');

echo "Daycare Active 1: ".$daycareactive;

function setFirstAvailablePage(){
   global $daycareactive, $oscactive, $preschoolactive, $ecsactive, $grouphomeactive, $dayhomeactive, $otheractive;

   echo "Daycare Active 2: ".$daycareactive;

   ...other stuff goes here
}
```

The above results in:

```
Daycare Active 1: N
Daycare Active 2:
```

Why is the second one blank?

I'm using the keyword global, so as far as I understand it that's supposed to bring in the variables as defined outside of this function.  Why is it not working?

Comment: You are obviously missing something, I do not see the call to `setFirstAvailablePage()`.

Comment: .. and that's why you don't want to rely to the global state, like, ever. When you call `setFirstAvailablePage`, probably global `daycareactive` changed. Or the very first `daycareactive` is not in the global scope at all.

Comment: `as far as I understand it that's supposed to bring in the variables as defined outside of this function` that tecnically incorrect btw, you can check php's "variable scope" for more insight. `setFirstAvailablePage` is not a closure.

Comment: The call to setFirstAvailablePage actually happens in another script that includes this script.  I'm guessing that's where my problem lies.

Comment: This is also a good reason for not using `global`.  If you need data in a function then pass it in, this makes testing easier.